# Boolean always returns false when called from other class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables

Ok, I am a bit of a noob at Objective C and programing in general, but i'm trying to learn, so i would appreviate a bit of help.

I am making a game with several classes. On the main menu screen I have 2 buttons, easy and hard, and a start game button. At the moment, I have declared a public boolean called "level" in the class MainView, then in the hard button action I set level to true, in the easy button action I set it to false. In a different class I have imported MainView.h and in a method called "numberOfCards" I have:

```
MainView *view = [[MainView alloc]init];

if(view->level){
   cards = 10;

}

else {
   cards = 20;
}
```

But level always returns false, I'm guessing that when I initialise my MainView, it resets the variable?

Am I tackling this problem in the wrong way?
Any help would be great.

Heres some more code:

MainView.h

```
@interface MainView : UIViewController <HostViewControllerDelegate, JoinViewControllerDelegate, GameViewControllerDelegate>
{

@public
BOOL level;

}

@end
```

mainView.m

```
- (IBAction)easyButton:(id)sender 
{

level = NO;
}

- (IBAction)hardButton:(id)sender
{
level = YES;
}
```

Comment: share more code, please.

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the code, I meant false

Answer (score 0):

You say, "I'm guessing that when I initialise my MainView, it resets the variable?"

Effectively, yes.  More specifically, it creates a new object that has its own `level` variable, and the default value of an uninitialized BOOL is NO.

You need to pass a reference to the existing `MainView` object into the object that needs to request the level information.  Exactly how to do that depends on your program structure and how the two classes are related to each other.

Comment: Is there any way you could give some sort of example?

Comment: How/where do you create your original `MainView` controller that handles the button touches?  What creates the object that contains the `numberOfCards` method?

Comment: MainView is a class, not sure what you mean by how or where i created it. numberOfCards is in a class called cards.m, which is a subclass of NSObject

Comment: When your program runs, objects usually get created either because you call `alloc` on their class, or make a copy of existing ones, or because they get loaded from some external source...like when you create them in a storyboard or xib file.  To have a chance of helping you, I need to know how these two objects are connected.  Does the `MainView` create the `cards`, or does something else create both of them, or...?